# Page load failed with error: The network connection was lost. Using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to run a dynamic web application from eclipse. I am using wildfly-10.0.0.Final as the server. I installed jboss tools.

As a test I created a dynamic web project called 'test', and added an index.html file in the WebContent directory with simply "hi" in p tags.

I start the server, which is running fine, hit 'Run On Server', and immediately get the error message:

http://localhost:8080/tester/index.html

Page load failed with error: The network connection was lost.

So far I have tried a full clean uninstall of eclipse, downloading wildly, adding jboss tools, and trying again, yet the same issue occurs. I have looked on the Eclipse forums, but they are of no help.

This problem occurred out of the blue.

wildfly admin works at the url:

http://127.0.0.1:9990/management

unable to access localhost:8080/

I tried this with intelliJ and am getting the same issue. Getting the error message from google:
The localhost page isn't working
localhost didn't send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

03:49:12,347 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.4) 
03:49:12,671 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /tester
03:49:12,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "tester.war" (runtime-name : "tester.war")
03:49:12,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
03:49:12,748 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
03:49:12,748 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 3163ms - Started 336 of 627 services (382 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Connected to server

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether index.html is present in the list welcome file in web.xml

and right click the project name and select Run on server,

if u directly use run on server from index.html,it will try to run that page only not the entire application

i think that's it

Answer (score 0):

> Page load failed with error: The network connection was lost.

Your URL is pointing to the wrong port. You are saying that you are running Wildfly on port 9x. So you need to change the URL to point to 9080 instead of 8080. Go to the servers tab in Eclipse and change the HTTP port there to 9080.

Comment: This just means I can access the management port via http://127.0.0.1:9990/management, but I tried your method, the result remains the same.